# Sync status of ethereum node

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a four node setup and have get method in smartcontract to get the status of certain application. Currently the api invocation is happening at any node ( any of  four nodes). For example if one of the node is syncing to other nodes ( was down for some time) in the network and if my api call is triggered at the syncing node the data which I am getting won't be the latest one. So is there anyway to identify the node is in sync with network and then perform the api get call or am I wrong with my understatnding.

Answer (score 2):

Is my node connected to peers?

```
web3.net.peerCount
```

Is my node syncing?

```
web3.eth.syncing
```

Is my node fully synced? (should be 0)

```
web3.eth.syncing.highestBlock - web3.eth.syncing.currentBlock
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use method [`web3.eth.isSyncing`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#issyncing) to know whether node is still synchronizing.  You may use [`web3.eth.getBlockNumber`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getblocknumber) to know what block node is currently at.

You better check both, because node may think that it is synchronized, but may actually be disconnected form the network.

Answer (score 1):

As say in other answer you should use `web3.eth.isSyncing` but just to be precise this function :

- if is synced, returns `false`
- if is syncing, returns `startingBlock`, `currentBlock`, `highestBlock`, `knownStates` `pulledStates`
- if is just started / not connected to other nodes, returns `false`

The last case can be tricky as it gives you false positive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trustray open source

Comment: Hi there. Can you include some more information about _how_ to use the application in a way that answers the question?

Comment: Is more for you: https://github.com/TrustWallet/trust-ray